# RegexLike code won't return numbers that start with 0

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to return numbers from strings that are either whole numbers (positive or negative) or numbers to two decimal places, however the code seems to be ignoring numbers that start with 0, I am hoping for some help on how to fix this issue, the code is as follows :

```
WITH A AS(
SELECT CURRENT_BALANCE, ( CASE WHEN (REGEXP_LIKE(CURRENT_BALANCE,'^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$')) then 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS T FROM BALANCE_TABLE )

SELECT * FROM A
WHERE T = 0 
LIMIT 1
```

-- The regexp_like is where the issue lies, the code above just returned to me the numbers that weren't being picked up

Edit: Example of what is not returned: 0.00, -0.07, 0.04
Thank you

Comment: Please provide examples of what matches and what doesn't match when you think it should.  Also, why would `current_balance` be stored as a string?

Comment: Sorry I have added examples to the post, and honestly just how the table was initially setup - presumably as to be able to add N/A or otherwise to distinguish where we are missing information as opposed to just a null

Comment: Your code treats the stated values the same way it treats integers:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=9d5d1bf56ab11c39de8c6f32a29f19b4.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `WHERE T = 1`

```
WITH A AS(
SELECT CURRENT_BALANCE, ( CASE WHEN (REGEXP_LIKE(CURRENT_BALANCE,'^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$')) then 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS T FROM BALANCE_TABLE )

SELECT * FROM A
WHERE T = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That would return the attributres that met the REGEXP_LIKE criteria, however I used the code to find the strings that didn't, i am looking for help as to why the following do not meet the criteria and how to fix it : 0.00 , 0.06 , -0.04

Comment: Would you please share sample data from BALANCE_TABLE against which this is not working.

Comment: Either tell what's wrong with the result of the statement at the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e2045bbc86d113e4fe440281ea732f71) or edit this statement with your data, provide the corresponding link and describe what's wrong with the result on your data.